# docker-compose.yaml should extend definition from external file + docker-compose.override.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Directory/ file hierarchy:

- root/docker-compose.yaml
- root/docker-compose.override.yml
- root/Dockerfile

---

- root/External/docker-compose.yaml
- root/External/docker-compose.override.yml
- root/External/Dockerfile

docker-compose.yaml in External directory has definiton of service_b and docker-compose.yaml in root directory has defintioon of service_a.

I want to include docker-compose.yaml from External directory to docker-compose.yaml in root directory, so docker-compose.yaml in root directory looks like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    service_a:
        image: service_a
        build: 
            context: .
            target: service_a
    service_b:
        extends:
            file: "External/docker-compose.yaml"
            service: service_b
```

Issue: file "root/External/docker-compose.override.yml" is ignored...
Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Docker/Compose do you have?  The very new [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extends) claims to support `extends:` at a service level, but requires version 2 of the Compose tool (built into the `docker` binary); otherwise, [`extends:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) isn't supported in a `version: "3.x"` Compose file.

Comment: docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c. I can update docker-compose if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are four versions of the Compose file format, depending on the tools you have available.  Docker has recently started distributing a rewritten Compose as a [plugin for the `docker` binary](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) and this supports a newer [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).  If `docker-compose --version` tells you it's a 1.x version, then your tool only supports [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) (slightly more suited to single-host installations) and [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) (slightly more suited to Swarm installations) (and the very old version 1, for which the Compose tool version 2 drops support).

Service-level `extends:` is [not supported for Compose file version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services), only for version 2 and the [Specification format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extends).

| Compose file version | Version 1 | Version 2 | Version 3 | Specification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supports `extends:` | no | YES | no | YES |
| Works in `docker-compose` v1 | YES | YES | YES | no |
| Works in `docker compose` v2 | no | YES | YES | YES |

The easiest workaround is to change your Compose file version back to version 2.  There's no particular downside to doing this, unless you're also trying to deploy using Docker Swarm and need resource constraints there.

```yaml
version: "2.4"
```

Comment: I have changed root/docker-compose.yaml version to 2.4 but still it doesn't work.